# HTML5 & Bootstrap 4 Responsive iframe Video height is too small

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to embed a responsive iframe with a Vimeo video into my website. The issue is, when I load the page, the iframe is too short so it cuts off the video's timeline, pause and play buttons like so:
[image: Website Screenshot]

Previously, I had a `margin-top:4.6em;` applied to the iframe in my CSS to push the next container below the view, which I removed as I thought it could be the issue. It solve the height problem on the offline site, but the online version still does it.
(offline site)
[image: Offline Loaded Site]

I'm running it on Google Chrome and my code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-4 col-xs-10 offset-xs-1 text-xs-center">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe height="100%" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/168167917"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS (although, not very relevant):

```
body {
    background-image: url(/img/pic.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-top:70px;
}
.footer {
    margin-left:1em;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:1.5em;
    -webkit-text-stroke:.5px #000000;
}
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.0 Alpha 5 from the current maxCDN, Google and netdna CDNs. Can anybody help me?